Confused about the nuances between 매일 and 맨날
I’ve come across mixed opinions regarding the usage of 매일 and 맨날. Some say they’re completely interchangeable, with the only difference being that 매일 is more formal and 맨날 is more informal. However, I’ve also seen others suggest that 맨날 carries a slightly negative or complaining tone, particularly in sentences like:
또 카페? 맨날 카페만 가면 지겹지 않아?
The argument is that 맨날 can imply boredom or exasperation due to the repeated action, similar to how we might say “always” or “all the time” with a bit of frustration in English (e.g., “We always go to the same restaurant!”).
Can anyone clarify whether there’s truly a difference in connotation between these two words, or are they just interchangeable depending on formality?

매일 and 맨날 both translates to every day. However, 매일 is used more often to represent daily occurrences while 맨날 is closer to "Every single time".
Yes, there is a negative connotation on 맨날 that 매일 does not have. If you want to express "always" without negative connotation, you can use "항상" as a replacement of "맨날'.
